# prepend symbolic link filename

Tags: linux, bash, function, for-loop, symlink

I need a function to prefix any filename starting with 'nfcapd'

original fileset:

```
/root/netflow3/nfcapd.201402090310 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402090310
/root/netflow3/nfcapd.201402050400 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402050400
/root/netflow3/nfcapd.201402100730 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402100730
/root/netflow3/1.nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/e/nfcapd.201402100730
/root/netflow3/2.nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/f/nfcapd.201402100730
```

with prefix="foo_":

```
/root/netflow3/foo_nfcapd.201402090310 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402090310
/root/netflow3/foo_nfcapd.201402050400 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402050400
/root/netflow3/foo_nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402100730
/root/netflow3/1.nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/e/nfcapd.201402100730
/root/netflow3/2.nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/f/nfcapd.201402100730
```

I came up with a function that can add a prefix to any symlink:

```
readonly PATH_CURRENT_SCRIPT="$(dirname $0)"

sym_rename () {
        local PATH_SOURCE_FILES=$1
        local prefix=$2

        [[ ! -d $PATH_SOURCE_FILES ]] && echo "path $dir not found!  Exiting...." && exit 1

        cd $PATH_SOURCE_FILES
        for f in * ; do mv "$f" "${prefix}_$f" ; done
        cd $PATH_CURRENT_SCRIPT
}
```

The only problem is that it prefixes everything:

with prefix="foo_":

```
/root/netflow3/foo_nfcapd.201402090310 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402090310
/root/netflow3/foo_nfcapd.201402050400 -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402050400
/root/netflow3/foo_nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/b/nfcapd.201402100730
/root/netflow3/foo_1.nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/e/nfcapd.201402100730
/root/netflow3/foo_2.nfcapd.201402100730  -> /a/f/nfcapd.201402100730
```

How can I modify the function to only prefix symlink filenames that start with "nfcapd" ?

Comment: Note that your code will prefix *any* file, not just symlinks. You might want to consider testing each file with `-h` before renaming it. `[[ -h $f ]] && mv "$f" "${prefix}_$f"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your glob to match what you want:

```
    cd $PATH_SOURCE_FILES
    shopt -s nullglob
    for f in nfcapd* ; do mv "$f" "${prefix}_$f" ; done
    shopt -u nullglob
    cd $PATH_CURRENT_SCRIPT
```

Comment: Or more specifically, that the file is a symbolic link with `-h`.

Comment: @chepner Woops, didn't read the question all the way. As `chepner`, mentioned should definitely test `[[ -h $f ]] && mv ...` and probably quote your variables if you want to avoid issues.

Comment: @Markku That didn't work.  I got an error, "mv: cannot stat `nfcapd*': No such file or directory"

Comment: @brakertech It sounds like there were no matching files in `$PATH_SOURCE_FILES`, so the pattern was treated as literal text instead of expanding to a list of file names. Testing that `$f` exists (and a symlink, if appropriate) will avoid that problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer for this situation -- setting the `nullglob` option will avoid the for loop if there are no matching files.